# How does angular-cli@webpack work?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have used angular-cli with systemJS and am now comfortable with its build process,test cases & component interaction.

recently I upgraded my `angular-cli` to `angular-cli@webpack`.

But I am pretty confused with following things:

1. How does webpack build process works?
2. How can I install third party libraries like `lodash,ng2-bootstrap` etc with this webpack configuration as I cant see any `webpack.config.ts` file.
3. Why does it not show any bundle which contains JS files of my application?
4. I can only see typescript files of my application..why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. When u run `ng build` it will build everything and output the files to the Dist folder
2. Just run `npm install 'external-dependency'` and you're good to go, just import it in the files u need it (and in app.module.ts)
3. U need to run `ng build` first, see 1
4. See 1

Comment: there is no dist folder when working with angular-cli@webpack

Comment: run ng build and you will see the dist folder. I'm also running angular-cli@webpack.

Answer (score 0):

1. webpack read entry and build to desired output. here is an example

   ```
    entry: {
           'app': './main.ts'//your entry point
    }, output: {
      path: helpers.root('dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js' //your build file
   }
   ```
2. It's simple, install your dependencies through npm and require them in your project and webpack will take care of them means it will bundle them into your build.

   ### Example

   `npm install lodash`

and in your project

```
require("lodash")
```

3. when you run application with ng-serve it does not build physicals files, it serve from memory and tha't why you don't see any file.
4. As long you are running your application with `ng-serve`  it will not show you physicals files but if you run ng-build it will build physicals files to dist folder and you will be able to see them.

### [read more about webpack it's awesome](https://webpack.github.io/docs/)